# Error selecting DataSet for AXDataSource in Visual Studio for Enterprise Portal development (AX 2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dataset, datasource, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, enterprise-portal

I'm working on EP development for AX 2012 R2.
When I try to add a DataSet that contains custom fields on standard tables or custom tables for a AXDataSource (in my EP user control) I receive this errors:

'DataSource "CustTable" in DataSet "DataSet1" has an unknown field "Field1"'

'Table with an id of "Table1" does not exist'

I tried to delete all the .auc files but I receive still the same problem.

At the moment I'm working with visual studio and the AOS installed on different machines.

Thanks,

Luca Ganz

Comment: I'm also receiving an error upon addition of a table to existing DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by compiling the entire project which contains the objects in AX and then close AX,delete cache and then restart AOS and also close Visual Studio before restarting AOS. 
Then I am 100% sure this error will not come .